# Suggestions on a short piece of Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm very new to Haskell and as a way of learning (first project) I am porting code from Tcl to Haskell. The project is a domain specific query language which is translated to SQL queries via a semantic layer. Now, with the operators of the query language restricted in the parser for the language, code similar to this actually seems more silly in Haskell than it did in Tcl :-)

```
type MatchOperator = [Char]

getOpJoiner :: MatchOperator -> String
getOpJoiner "!=" = " and "
getOpJoiner "!~" = " and "
getOpJoiner "!~~" = " and "
getOpJoiner _  = " or "  -- In reality, this can only be "=", "~", "~~" or "==" according to the parser
```

The code does what is should do (return the appropriate SQL logical joiner of statements depending on the query operator used), but I'm sure it can be made more pretty.

Comment: My guess is that you probably want to add some more typing to that to make sure you would not end up with syntactically incorrect sql?

Comment: What you probably want to do if you were to do it the "Haskell way" is use a parser like parsec to convert your DSL into a concrete data type then generate a SQL query from it.  This would be the safe way to do things, even if it takes more code.  Sure, your code will probably be longer than in Tcl, but it'll certainly be a lot safer, robust, and if done correctly more extendable.

Comment: There are many reasons why I am trying to port my code to Haskell, for sure. ;-) Now, what I would like to do somehow is to compress lines 1-3 somehow.

Comment: didierc: can you have a the type system involved here actually, since the operator could be "=" for instance. I was planning to make sure that the input was correct in the parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to cut down on the lines of code, try this:

```
getOpJoiner :: MatchOperator -> String
getOpJoiner x
            | x `elem` ["!=","!~","!~~"] = " and "
            | otherwise = " or "
```

`elem` is used to check if the input matches any of the strings in the list.

This function will work. However, I think it would be better to invest in the solution suggested by @bheklilr for the reasons he mentions.